# Arranging $6$ distinct rooks on a $6\times 6$ board

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> How many ways there are to arrange $6$ distinct rooks on a $6\times 6$ board such that no rook would threaten another?

My attempt:

1st rook: $36$ options.

2nd rook: $36-10+2=28$, there are 10 squares that the first rook threaten, 2 joint squares so to avoid counting them twice we add them.

3rd rook: $28-10+2=20$, 4th: $12$, 5th: $4$, 6th: only one square left.

So the final answer is: $36\cdot28\cdot20\cdot12\cdot4\cdot1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166167/placing-9-black-and-9-white-rooks-on-6-times6-board-without-any-attacks-b/1166198#comment2377000_1166198

Comment: @SrinivasK similar but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Israel's hint is correct. This is just to expand on his hint and explain the intuition. 
As a rook threatens every other piece in its own row and column, to fit 6 rooks on a 6x6 chessboard, there must be one rook in each row and in each column.

### Method 1

There is a natural bijection between an (unordered) solution and the permutations on $[1...6]$ defined by the vertical position of the rook in the first column through the sixth column. Thus there are $6!$ (unordered solutions). Now, for each solution there are six spots on the board to populate with 6 distinct rooks, therefore there are $6!$ distinct solutions for each unordered solution. In total there are $(6!)^2$ solutions.

### Method 2

The first rook can choose from 6 columns and 6 rows within that column (36 spots). The second rook can choose from the 5 remaining columns and 5 remaining rows (25). The third rook can choose from the 4 remaining columns and 4 remaining rows (16), and so on. Therefore there are $6^2\times5^2\times4^2\times3^2\times2^2\times1^2=(6!)^2$ solutions

Comment: The second method is nice. What do you mean by solutions in the first method?

Comment: An unordered solution is an arrangement of rooks on a chess board such that none threaten another rook. As there is a bijection between permutations on [1...6] and unordered solutions. The number of unordered solutions is the same as the number of permutations on the set (6!). This is basically how many ways we can choose the positions the rooks will occupy. As your rooks are distinct (labelled), each unordered solution has 6! ordered solutions as for each choice of 6 spots, we can place six distinct rooks 6! ways.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There must be one rook in each row and one in each column.  Relate the (unordered) set of positions of the rooks to permutations of $1,2,\ldots, 6$.
Then think about labelling the rooks.